# Compare 2 dates in XSD using assert

Tags: xml, xsd

Hi im looking for comparing dates with current date.

End should be greater than current date, tried with above assertion failing. Any ideas why the following xsd <xs:assert test="dateTime(packages/package/data/end/text()) gt dateTime(current-date())"/>

snippet is causing a validation error?

```
<packages >
    <package >
        <data>
            <end>2021-12-31T12:21:26-05:00</end>
        </data>
    </package>
</packages>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error? It's always easier to diagnose an error if you know what it is.

Two suggestions come to mind, (a) should the function be prefixed `xs:dateTime()`, and (b) is the context item for the path correct?

Answer (score 0):

thanks it helped me

<xs:assert test= "xs:dateTime(packages/package/data/end/text()) gt xs:dateTime(current-date())" />

this one worked for me. removed empty and added xs:dateTime.